# Add all the row values from file1 to file2, if a column value in file1 exists in file2

Tags: awk

I have two files

FileA

```bsh
Aacs    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
Abracl  2824    19.31   58.45   55.67   33.075
Ackr3   1294.5  19.5    47.5    38.5    4.5
Actb    246564  4472.46 11134.1 12272.6 2228.05
```

FileB

```
chr5    124350754       124353027       Aacs    1639_47_175_59_95
chr5    125140780       125141989       Aacs    920_132_115_65_389
chr5    125148638       125149481       Aacs    357_56_65_48_116
chr1    89576587        89577508        Ackr3   618_804_385_412_1239
chr1    89579859        89582071        Ackr3   1340_429_274_242_611
chr5    142819302       142820142       Actb    614_116_105_58_371
chr5    142821400       142822219       Actb    544_74_97_45_118
```

If a value in column1 of FileA exists in FileB, I need to add all row values from FileA to FileB, even when that matched value occurs multiple  times in FileB.

So since *Aacs* in FileA exists in FileB, I want all corresponding values to get added like this multiple times into FileB:

```bsh
chr5    124350754       124353027       Aacs    1639_47_175_59_95    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
chr5    125140780       125141989       Aacs    920_132_115_65_389    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
chr5    125148638       125149481       Aacs    357_56_65_48_116    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
```

I can do this in Python using pandas but would love to find a way to do this using awk or other unix toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{key=$1; sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,""); a[key]=$0; next} {print $0 a[$4]}' FileA FileB
chr5    124350754       124353027       Aacs    1639_47_175_59_95    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
chr5    125140780       125141989       Aacs    920_132_115_65_389    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
chr5    125148638       125149481       Aacs    357_56_65_48_116    4498.5  778.5   995.5   1263    530
chr1    89576587        89577508        Ackr3   618_804_385_412_1239   1294.5  19.5    47.5    38.5    4.5
chr1    89579859        89582071        Ackr3   1340_429_274_242_611   1294.5  19.5    47.5    38.5    4.5
chr5    142819302       142820142       Actb    614_116_105_58_371    246564  4472.46 11134.1 12272.6 2228.05
chr5    142821400       142822219       Actb    544_74_97_45_118    246564  4472.46 11134.1 12272.6 2228.05
```

If you want the fields aligned in the output there's lots of options, the simplest being to just pipe to `column`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{key=$1; sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,""); a[key]=$0; next} {print $0 a[$4]}' FileA FileB | column -t
chr5  124350754  124353027  Aacs   1639_47_175_59_95     4498.5  778.5    995.5    1263     530
chr5  125140780  125141989  Aacs   920_132_115_65_389    4498.5  778.5    995.5    1263     530
chr5  125148638  125149481  Aacs   357_56_65_48_116      4498.5  778.5    995.5    1263     530
chr1  89576587   89577508   Ackr3  618_804_385_412_1239  1294.5  19.5     47.5     38.5     4.5
chr1  89579859   89582071   Ackr3  1340_429_274_242_611  1294.5  19.5     47.5     38.5     4.5
chr5  142819302  142820142  Actb   614_116_105_58_371    246564  4472.46  11134.1  12272.6  2228.05
chr5  142821400  142822219  Actb   544_74_97_45_118      246564  4472.46  11134.1  12272.6  2228.05
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply join two files using [join(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

```
join -1 1 -2 4 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6 FileA FileB
```

Just specify on which columns **-1** and **-2** of files 1 (FileA) and 2 (FileB) you want to join. The **-o** is just to fit your example output. If you want the output in nice columns pipe the output into `column -t`